# How to avoid impersonation of a token with same name or symbol?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, contract-deployment

When you generate a token you can set a name and symbol, but this is not unique, that means that another smart contract made by another person may have the same name or symbol.

Is this a problem if a hacker wants to impersonate a token to make operations on behalf of the real token?

How can this be avoid? Or there is something in the creation of the token than makes impersonation not possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do to avoid this.
That is why you will see most ICO owners go the extra mile to communicate the exact address someone should be making a transfer to. 
You can't trust neither the token name nor the symbol, only the address.

There was a proposal going around for building a registry of token names/symbols so they would be unique, but I don't know where that stands as of this date.

Comment: That solves the problem at the initial coin distribution, but how to avoid for example to receive impersonated tokens at an exchange?